# How to override findById with projection in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my repository, i need to use Projection for the findById method:

```
@Repository
public interface ForumRepository extends CrudRepository<Forum,Integer> {
        ForumDTO findById(Integer id);
}
```

But since the findByID already exist in CrudRepository so I can't override this with different return type, is there other way I can archive it ?

Answer (score 6):

I've just figured out I don't need to override it since I can just use `getBy` instead of `findBy`:

```
public interface ForumRepository extends CrudRepository<Forum,Integer> {
        ForumDTO getById(Integer id);
}
```

Comment: since SpringFramwork JPA ver 2.5, `getById()` is the built-in method in JpaRepository

Comment: its a lightbulb moment. Genius!!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can generalize the method and pass in the dto class.

```
<T> T findById(Integer id, Class<T> type);
```

This works with Optional too.

```
<T> Optional<T> findById(String id, Class<T> type);
```

---

In order to use this, you will have to pass in the type you want to get back.

```
ForumDTO forum = forumRepo.findById(378583, ForumDTO.class);
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to include Entity name in the method name, like:

```
@Repository
public interface ForumRepository extends JpaRepository<Forum, Integer> {

    Optional<ForumProjection> findForumById(Integer id);
}
```

This won't *@Override* the CrudRepository *findById(...)* method.